# No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found when installing SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pycharm

I am using python 3.9.8 and pycharm on a macbook m1.
I have already installed openblas with homebrew but I still get the error below.
I tried installing SciPy via homebrew, but it didn't work properly.
My pip is up to date.

I installed Numpy, Pandas etc. Everything works fine except SciPy and I can't figure out why.

```
(venv) wes@Air-van-Wes pythonProject % pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.7.2.tar.gz (36.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/bl/2xjy80bj6y57yb5z0frfypk00000gn/T/tmpgb5a46oi
       cwd: /private/var/folders/bl/2xjy80bj6y57yb5z0frfypk00000gn/T/pip-install-19slhbw2/scipy_f4bfaae68a1e4c2db88f86a394b879ca
  Complete output (175 lines):
  setup.py:491: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/bl/2xjy80bj6y57yb5z0frfypk00000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-6yn5g0q3'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
    warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
  Running from SciPy source directory.
  Running scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py
  Running scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py
  Running scipy/stats/_generate_pyx.py
  Processing scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx
  Processing scipy/cluster/_optimal_leaf_ordering.pyx
  Processing scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.pyx
  Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_cytest.pyx
  Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx
  Processing scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.pyx
  Processing scipy/linalg/_matfuncs_sqrtm_triu.pyx
  Processing scipy/linalg/_solve_toeplitz.pyx
  Processing scipy/linalg/cython_blas.pyx
  Processing scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.pyx.in
  Processing scipy/optimize/_group_columns.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/_bglu_dense.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/_trlib/_trlib.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_constants.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_wrapper.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/_lsq/givens_elimination.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/cython_optimize/_zeros.pyx.in
  Processing scipy/io/matlab/mio_utils.pyx
  Processing scipy/io/matlab/streams.pyx
  Processing scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx
  Processing scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.pyx
  Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_def.pyx
  Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_call.pyx
  Processing scipy/_lib/messagestream.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/cython_special.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/_comb.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/_test_round.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs.pyx
  Processing scipy/fftpack/convolve.pyx
  Processing scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx
  Processing scipy/interpolate/_bspl.pyx
  Processing scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.pyx.in
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_shortest_path.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_traversal.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_flow.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_tools.pyx
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:9:8: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:13:4: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:21:8: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:25:4: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:33:8: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:37:4: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:45:8: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:49:4: Unreachable code
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_matching.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_reordering.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_min_spanning_tree.pyx
  Processing scipy/spatial/ckdtree.pyx
  Processing scipy/spatial/_voronoi.pyx
  Processing scipy/spatial/_hausdorff.pyx
  Processing scipy/spatial/qhull.pyx
  Processing scipy/spatial/transform/rotation.pyx
  Processing scipy/signal/_max_len_seq_inner.pyx
  Processing scipy/signal/_peak_finding_utils.pyx
  Processing scipy/signal/_upfirdn_apply.pyx
  Processing scipy/signal/_spectral.pyx
  Processing scipy/signal/_sosfilt.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_stats.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_qmc_cy.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_sobol.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/biasedurn.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/nbinom_ufunc.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/binom_ufunc.pyx
  Cythonizing sources
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  openblas_clapack_info:
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  flame_info:
    libraries flame not found in ['/Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['/Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  /private/var/folders/bl/2xjy80bj6y57yb5z0frfypk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-4znp06oe/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  /private/var/folders/bl/2xjy80bj6y57yb5z0frfypk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-4znp06oe/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "/private/var/folders/bl/2xjy80bj6y57yb5z0frfypk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-4znp06oe/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 166, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "/private/var/folders/bl/2xjy80bj6y57yb5z0frfypk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-4znp06oe/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 258, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "/private/var/folders/bl/2xjy80bj6y57yb5z0frfypk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-4znp06oe/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 631, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 627, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "/private/var/folders/bl/2xjy80bj6y57yb5z0frfypk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-4znp06oe/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "setup.py", line 529, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError(msg)
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.
  To build Scipy from sources, BLAS & LAPACK libraries need to be installed.
  See site.cfg.example in the Scipy source directory and
  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html for details.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/23/58c4f995475a2a97cb5f4a032aedaf881ad87cd976a7180c55118d105a1d/scipy-1.7.2.tar.gz#sha256=fa2dbabaaecdb502641b0b3c00dec05fb475ae48655c66da16c9ed24eda1e711 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/) (requires-python:>=3.7,<3.11). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python /Users/wes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/bl/2xjy80bj6y57yb5z0frfypk00000gn/T/tmpgb5a46oi Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Notice that the error message points to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html , which has a section on compiling on macOS, including instructions for installing BLAS and LAPACK.

Comment: Yeah on there it said to install it via homebrew which I did. But it still gave me this error even though I installed openBLAS.

Comment: Have you also checked and, if necessary, edited the site.cfg file as mentioned earlier in the error message?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found/64537744#64537744.    Helped me.

Answer (score 25):

I encountered the same issue, using Homebrew based Python 3.10 installation and installing [Poetry based package depending on Scipy](https://pypi.org/project/tradingstrategy/).

The error was:

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.
```

How I fixed this:

```sh
# Install lapack and openblas from Homebrew
brew install openblas lapack

# Tell Numpy installer where to find lapack
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/lapack/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/pkgconfig"

# See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/12935
export CFLAGS=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration


# The location may vary - use find command to find this on your local /usr/local/opt
export LAPACK=/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/liblapack.dylib
export BLAS=/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.19.dylib
```

And then attempting to install the packages again with:

```
# Install deps
poetry install
```

poetry / pip / etc. installation methods should be interchangeable.

SciPy 1.6.1 installation will take some time, but this time will complete.

- Tip about [how `LAPACK` environment variable works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325222/correct-way-to-point-to-atlas-blas-lapack-libraries-for-numpy-build)

Some of the official documentation (less useful):

- [The official Scipy installation instructions](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/macosx.html).
- [The official LAPACK installation instructions](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/#_users_guide)

Comment: I had the same issue was OP, but for an Intel Macbook. I was able to run `poetry add scipy` after running only the first line of the fix above, i.e. `brew install openblas lapack`. Thanks!

Comment: N.B. OpenBLAS provides LAPACK, as well. Installing a separate LAPACK may give you a generic (unoptimized) version, rather than OpenBLAS's optimized LAPACK. See: https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/Installation-Guide

Comment: You are a true hero!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 15):

Mikko Ohtamaa's method didn't work for me.. I could see why, my brew packages happened to be installed somewhere else and some of the libraries were slightly newer.

It's worth being aware of this. You can see where brew puts stuff easily by just doing this after installing openblas:

```
brew info openblas
```

So in the end I had to do:

```
 brew install openblas lapack

 export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib"
 export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/include"
 export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib"
 export CPPFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/include"
 export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/pkgconfig"
 export CFLAGS=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration
 export LAPACK=/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib/liblapack.dylib
 export BLAS=/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.dylib
 
 poetry install
```

Still, I'd be nowhere without Mikko's answer. I've tried a couple of other methods that didn't work, so I don't know if that's because I'm on a newer M1 or because brew changed or what..

Answer (score 4):

For Debian/Ubuntu with a virtualenv (poetry):

```
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt install gfortran
```

Then install skipy to your virtual env and wait a *very long time* for it to build (eg: 10 minutes!)

```
poetry add scipy scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded conda and now it works just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

While OpenBLAS is important to install, it appears that we don't need to point to it in compiler flags. This means that the solution doesn't need to change when a different version of OpenBLAS is present:

```
brew install openblas lapack

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib/pkgconfig"
export LAPACK=/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib/liblapack.dylib

poetry add scipy
```